# lightning-datatable - Actions

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a lightng-datatable that uses actions.  Sometimes, all of the actions are not displaying on my page.  For example, if I only have a few records, all actions are not displaying. See attached screenshot.  Is there a way to ensure that all of the actions are displayed when clicking the actions drop down?  Here is the field I define with the columns:

```
{label: 'Actions', type: 'action', fixedWidth: 90, fixedHeight: 90,
    typeAttributes: {
        rowActions: actions,
        menuAlignment: 'right'
    }
```

Thanks!!

[image]

Comment: Do you mean the action drop-down is hiding behind?

Comment: Yes, the actions in the action dropdown are not all exposed